# Как задать условия выполнения этого кода

Tags: php

Как сделать, чтобы при проверке переменной `$edf`
зависимости от значения переменной `$edf` выполнялся код

```
$edf=$data["wallet"];
if($edf=="";)
```

если переменная пустая то выполнялся код 1

```
{
$time = date("H:i:s d/m/Y");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
;}
```

если нет то код 2

```
{
$time = date("H:i:s d/m/Y");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($host==$ip){$host="UNKNOWN";};
$addres = $data["wallet"];
;}
```

Comment: Это какая-то шутка?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$edf=$data["wallet"];

if($edf==""){

$time = date("H:i:s d/m/Y");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

}else{

$time = date("H:i:s d/m/Y");
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
if($host==$ip){
$host="UNKNOWN";
}
$addres = $data["wallet"];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

//1 ВАРИАНТ
//ОПТИМАЛЬНЫЙ

$edf = $data['wallet'];


$time = date('H:i:s d/m/Y');
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if(!$edf){ //ЕСЛИ
    //СТРОКА ПУСТА? ИЛИ
    //ЗНАЧЕНИЕ == NULL
    //ТОГДА


    $user = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

}else{

    $host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    if($host == $ip){
        $host='UNKNOWN';
    }

    $address = $data['wallet'];
    //English, address
}


//2 ВАРИАНТ

$edf = $data['wallet'];

if($edf==''){
    $time = date('H:i:s d/m/Y');
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $user = $_SERVER ['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

}else{
    $time = date('H:i:s d/m/Y');
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $host = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
    if($host==$ip){
        $host='UNKNOWN';
    }
    $address = $data['wallet'];
    //English, address
}

// " не верно.
// читаем почему.

?>
```